# Android Transition Manager

Tags: android, android-transitions

I'm trying to set a TransitionManager in xml to manage all activity transitions but I'm having difficult to figure how.

Following the [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/TransitionManager.html) of the TransitionManager class,

1. I've created a XML file in res/transition/transition_manager.xml

   ```
   <transitionManager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

       <transition 
           android:fromScene="@layout/activity_launcher"
           android:toScene="@layout/activity_main" 
           android:transition="@transition/launcher_exit"/>

   </transitionManager>
   ```
2. I've created the Transition file (as example) in res/transition/launcher_exit.xml like this:

   ```
   <transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:transitionOrdering="sequential">

       <slide android:duration="500" android:slideEdge="left"/>
       <changeBounds />
       <slide android:duration="5000" android:slideEdge="right"/>

   </transitionSet>
   ```
3. And finally, I've settled in the style theme the following:

   ```
   <style name="AppTheme.Running" parent="android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar">

       <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
       <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
       <item name="android:gridViewStyle">@style/GridViewSytle</item>
       <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
       <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>

       <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowContentTransitionManager">@transition/transition_manager</item>
       <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>

   </style>
   ```
4. In the LauncherActivity, I'm launching the intent like this:

   ```
   ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this);
   Intent intent = new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
   ```

But unfortunately, the slide animation doesn't take effect. Please be aware, that i'm not trying to find how I can settle a slide animation, instead, I'm trying to figure out how I can make use of the TransitionManager (in xml) to manage my own custom transitions between activities.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your api version

Comment: compileSdkVersion 25 | minSdkVersion 21 | targetSdkVersion 25 | buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

Comment: Your mobile api version that mean mobile os

Comment: My testing mobile is marshmallow android (6.0.1)

Comment: Add the Java code Explode,Transacion or Slide (Transaction style)

Comment: Hi Raj, can you please be more clear? Thanks.

Comment: R u need just single navigation or that activity displays more image after move to next activity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149139/discussion-between-raj-and-while-true).